# Problem passing a dictionary value to an excel using openpyxl. (it inserts the value as 0)

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I'm making a script to automatize clothing orders, inserting them automatically to excel. Everything works perfectly except for this small part. On the first function I charge the values correctly, I've been checking that on the debugging tool of VSC. take talles (the input) as `6: 30`.

```
pedido_camisetas = r'test\Pedido de Camisetas de Rugby.xlsx'
wb_camisetas = openpyxl.load_workbook(pedido_camisetas, read_only= False)
ws_camisetas = wb_camisetas.active

#Post-Conditions: obtains a list with the asked talles (sizes), given by the user.
def ingreso_talles_camiseta_sin_numeracion():
    talles = input('Pasame los talles: ')
    talles = talles.split(' ') 
    while (talles[0] != 'N')&(talles[0] != 'n'):
        pasaje_lista_sin_numeracion(talles, '6')
        talles = input('Pasame los talles: ')
        talles = talles.split(' ')

#Pre-conditions: receive a list of talles (sizes) and the number or letter (in this testing case just number) referred to that size ("sigla").
#Post-conditions: Assings the number of sizes its proper key into the dictionary. The unchanged keys will remain on 0. 
def pasaje_lista_sin_numeracion(talles, sigla):
    dict_talles={6 : 0, 8 : 0, 10 : 0, 12 : 0, 14 : 0, 16 : 0, 'S' : 0, 'M' : 0, 'L' : 0, 'XL' : 0, 'XXL' : 0, 'XXXL' : 0, 'XXXXL   ' : 0,}    
    if talles[0] == (sigla + ':'):
        del talles[0]
        if sigla.isdigit():
            sigla = int(sigla)
        dict_talles[sigla] = int(talles[0])
    carga_excel_sin_numeracion(dict_talles, 6, 'D5')

# Pre: Will receive a dict with sizes and numbers, the number or letter referring to that size and the cell we want the excel to be completed
#Post: it will asing the sizes to the given cell and it will save the file
def carga_excel_sin_numeracion(diccionario, sigla, celda):
   
    ws_camisetas[celda] = diccionario[sigla]
    wb_camisetas.save(r'test\Pedido de Camisetas de Rugby.xlsx')
```

When I try to insert the dict value into the excel, the cell end up filled with a 0, nothing else.

Comment: `sizes` is missing so it's impossible to know what's being subsituted but as it stands `dicc[6]` will be `0`.

Comment: Got it, specified on the body text (I'm sorry its my first question)

Comment: this program is missing crucial parts, and almost look like code produced by random trial and error. Sorry - you won't be able to get any useful feedback with that. You might try at least posting your whole listing.

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks for the correction, it's my first question here and also my first personal project. Both my request here and my code may be a mess, let me know if now is more understandable or readable.

Comment: The dictionary doesn't seem to make any sense as all values are 0.